# Firebase Cloud Message iOS Swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got two iOS Swift Apps. The first one already exists in the App Store, let's say it is called "ExistingStoreApp". The second App I created only to test Push-Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), I call it "PushyTestApp".

What I do not understand: Sending Push-Notifications via Firebase-Console -> Notifications only works in PushyTestApp, but not with the ExistingStoreApp, although i did the same procedure on my ExistingStoreApp to make Firebase run. 
I did the following:

1. Create APNs AuthenticationKey in Apple Dev. Console (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)
2. Create App ID with explicit Bundle-ID (Difference between ExistingStoreApp and PushyTestApp here: ExistingStoreApp-App-ID already exists)
3. Create Provisioning-Profile
4. Create App (difference: ExistingStoreApp already exists)
5. Add CocoaPods with pod 'Firebase/Core' & pod 'Firebase/Messaging' -> pod install (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)
6. In Xcode App-Capabilities: Push Notifications turn ON, Remote Notifications under Background Modes turn ON
7. Use Existing Firebase-Project (Android running and working) and add new iOS App
8. Upload APN AuthKey to Firebase-Project-App
9. Download GoogleService-Info.plist -> Add to XCODE-Source dir
10. Fill AppDelegate.swift with example Code (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExamapleSwift/AppDelegate.swift)
11. Send Message via Firebase-Console with priority: high

result: PushyTestApp connected successful to Firebase, got FCM-Token, shows Message-content in XCODE-console. ExistingStoreApp connected successful to Firebase, got FCM-Token, **no reaction** when sending message with Firebase-Console.

I did not disable Method Sizzling. Which part did I miss? I thought it would be the Bundle-ID which is not conventional ("My-Company.My-Appname") but a similar Bundle-ID worked with PushyTestApp. Is it because the ExistingStoreApp is already a distributed App, an PushyTestApp is Development?

Comment: Does the Firebase console say the message was received?

Comment: @JenPerson Yes the Firebase Console says "Complete" for every message i did send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here comes the most strangest solution: Giving almost up the fight, I uploaded my App-Update to the App-Store with Firebase in code included. The AppStore told me to update my 1024pt App-Icon. I changed it, looked around in my Media.xcassets in XCode and spotted, that I had no icons for notifications defined. Added them, uploaded again to App-Store.

I tried one last time to send again a msg over Firebase-Console and ***bing***: Message received on iPhone. speechless.

Hope somebody helps this before going berserk