# Firebase Push Notifications not working, am I missing something?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send test notifications with FCM register token to device, but firebase is not sending the notifications.

I have:

- Created my app in Firebase
- Added my APNs Auth Key in Firebase's settings (tried with APNs certificates too)
- Added Firebase/Messaging && Firebase/Core to my Podfile
- Added GoogleService-Info.plist to my project
- Added Background Mode(remote notification) and Push Notifications in Capabilities
- Added [following code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#register_for_remote_notifications) to my App Delegate
- Even added FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = NO to my plist
- Tested with real device / simulator. App open && in background
- Also have [notification images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429863/firebase-cloud-message-ios-swift-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = NO from my plist` and added the APN certificates instead of the key and it worked